# Golang: How to terminate/abort/cancel inbound http request without response?

Tags: go, request, no-response

From server side I need to terminate/abort request without any response to client like [nginx's 444](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#how_to_prevent_undefined_server_names).

From client side it should look like connection reset by peer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've spent a couple hours and only accidentally find `http.Hijacker` which allows to get access to net connection from `http.ResponseWriter`:

```
h := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if wr, ok := w.(http.Hijacker); ok {
        conn, _, err := wr.Hijack()
        if err != nil {
           fmt.Fprint(w, err)
        }
        conn.Close()
    }
}
```

Terminating connection may be useful in some cases for saving CPU time and outbound traffic.